# Raphael JS fails

Tags: javascript, raphael

The following, very basic script, fails in Chrome and Safari with this error `Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="raphael-min.js">
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var paper = Raphael("canvas", 320, 200);

        </script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div id="canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have no idea why - anyone?

Comment: Can you rephrase the title as a question, or to be more specific (eg, add the error message) ?

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis - he already posted the error message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should wrap the call when the DOM is ready.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Using JQuery

$(function() {
    var paper = Raphael("canvas", 320, 200);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I certainly should! I just figured that out. It doesn't say that anywhere in the docs - I should know that really - but it should be in the docs!

Comment: well the examples have it. plus - just think - am i accessing the dom?

Comment: Virtually any javascript function that operates on an existing dom element will fail if you call it before creating the dom element.

Answer (score 1):

Or just call the function after you have defined the div...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="raphael-min.js">
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div id="canvas"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">var paper = Raphael("canvas", 320, 200);</script>
    </body>
</html>
```